# React Native iOS build Error - Check the render method of class

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I just started learning React Native iOS recently and I am following raywenderlich tutorial

https://www.raywenderlich.com/485-react-native-tutorial-building-ios-apps-with-javascript#toc-anchor-001

I am using following versions:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.60.5
```

In the Adding Navigation Section, I am following the exact same steps but getting following errors

```
"you likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in and you might have mixed up with default and named imports"
```

Here is my App.js file code

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, NavigatorIOS, View } from 'react-native';

class SearchPage extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
      return <Text style={styles.description}>Search for houses to buy! 
      </Text>;
 }
} 

class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
        <NavigatorIOS
         style={styles.container}
         initialRoute={{
           title: 'Property Finder',
           component: SearchPage,
         }}/>
         );
   }
  }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   description: {
     fontSize: 18,
     textAlign: 'center',
     color: '#656565',
     marginTop: 65,
   },
   container: {
     flex: 1,
   },
 });

 export default App;
```

Index.js file code:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: you seem to be missing `export default class App extends Component` . can you add that and try again?

Comment: No At the end I did the line  "export default App;".. Please check!!!

Comment: Got the same error... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try t ocheck import for registerComponent

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App'; // <--- check here

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder', () => App);
```

Comment: My index.js file code is exactly this. Please check the question edit...